# Error to receive emails google

Tags: email

since yesterday I have trouble to receive emails.
It was working well, but sunday morning I had to reset the server.
We have some address on google mail (ex: name@company.me) and since sunday evening, 3 emails aren't receive on 3 adresses, so it's randomly and not every time.
Do you have an idea of what is going on?

I have no idea at all and spen the day to fix it, without success.
This is part of the message:
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

name@company.me

Technical details of permanent failure: 
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain. We recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause of this error. The error that the other server returned was: 554 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied (state 14).

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you what to do.

> **We recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause of this error.** The error that the other server returned was: 554 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied (state 14)

We can't tell you why the other server sent that error, so you will need to contact the owners of the mail server that is generating the error.

Comment: No it sounds like the problem is with the server that Google are trying to contact.